# How can I count the occurrences of an element in a list and produce a new list?

Tags: scheme, racket

how can i change 
`(count-fruit ’(apple banana banana orange peach))`
to `'((apple 1) (banana 2) (orange 1) (grape 0)
(peach 1)))`
note that grape is also an exist kind of fruit so we cannot eliminate it from the list

Comment: What have you tried? What are your ideas on how to solve this? Nobody will show you code if you don't, but I might write ideas if you edit teh question with where you're stuck.

Comment: How did you get the grape there? Are you trying to implement a function that would take in 2 lists (a list of existing fruits, and a list of fruits to count)? You say that "grape is also an exist kind of fruit", how do we have a  way to determine if something is (or isn't) a fruit?

Comment: And where is the Litchi and Mango?

Comment: First write a function that computes how many times one symbol appears in a list. (I suspect that you have written something very similar very recently.) Think about how you can use that function. (Hint: `map` is your friend.)

Comment: @Sylwester and watermelon. I love watermelon. ^.^

Answer (score -1):

First off consider

```
(map (lambda (x) (cons x 0)) '(apple banana banana orange peach))
```

this will produce

```
((apple . 0) (banana . 0) (banana . 0) (orange . 0) (peach . 0))
```

next you can use a counter to make the number go up.

```
(let ((counter 0))
  (lambda (x)
    ;; you need to store the result (cons x counter)
    ;; in a temporary variable using LET here
    ;; then use SET! to increment counter
    ;; then return the temp
    ))
```

I've just given a template to get you started, if you have trouble finishing feel free to ask follow up questions. Hopefully the ideas are clear.